# Best way to connect to sql server online via asp.net site

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, networking

Situation:

I have a developed asp.net website that sits on our server behind our router, the website needs to be able to connect to a clients sql server instance from our server over the internet.

Additional Information:

My asp.net website is a data validation tool that runs hundreds of sql statements against an individuals databases to validate the data within.

Question:

1. What is the best way to do this?

And by best I mean, secure and also ease of implementation

Possible Solutions:

1. port forwarding on client side router and our router allowing only our IP access
2. Port knocking implementation
3. VPN

Any questions comments and concerns are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Best for what? What criteria are you interested in?

Comment: Respectfully, I think he said, "And by best I mean, secure and also ease of implementation"

Comment: in all fairness I made that edit after he asked the question

Comment: Is this application going to be used by numerous clients to use (or even manage) their db's? Or, is there a small, finite number of "providers" you're sharing data with?

Comment: It would be used by numerous clients to use (we do restrict access to running via user accounts)

Comment: Thank you for your help anyone, not sure why the -1 though with no comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your ASP.NET application *really* need to connect to a clients database?
This doesn't sound like a good idea.

- You can’t control the network on the other side
- The client may take down / alter / delete their database etc
- Usually, most people wouldn't be happy to allow connections to a database over
  the internet even if it was secured by firewall rules or VPN.
- Reluctant to allow authentication to internal resources from an external source

Some alternative solutions could be:

**Polling:**
An application that would run at the client side and contact your ASP.NET application, receive the data and then insert it into the database. This sounds similar to your inital intentions but with some slight differences. The client is initiating the communication so you don’t need to worry about connectivity, and the local application can also perform checking of the database / business rules / apply security such as HTTPS communication with your ASP.NET app etc.

**Client / Server:**
Similar to the Polling solution, you could have another application on the client side that would setup communication (maybe WCF net TCP / http SOAP), the client could register with your ASP.NET application and then you can send data to it whenever you want in a push architecture.

Both solutions above are just simple idea’s and not full implementation guidelines, but it might help you explore other avenues.

**Service:**
Could you store the data locally and provide a way for your clients to receive it rather than writing it directly to their databases? e.g. RSS / XML feeds for each client?

If the alternatives are not suitable for your implentation requirements, and you *must* to connect to many clients infrastructure I think you will need to support all of the options listed above as depending on their internal IT policies (if they are allowed to even accept external connections) they may stipulate which one they would prefer.

Answer (score 1):

The company I work for currently does this with a variety of systems. We've always just used a private B2B VPN connection between our network and the client's with only the ports necessary for our software open. That is probably going to be your best and easiest form of connection if the client is willing. We have this connection restricted to only wired connections and only from MAC addresses that are known to be company machines. But you can fine tune this to your application as necessary.

If you're looking for something a bit less intrusive I would suggest writing a WCF service that exposes the data you need to your website and have the customer install that, most clients would be willing to do that if they're looking to buy services from another company, at least in my experience.

Yet another option would be to make your site a "boxed" product as it were and sell the software to the client for them to install inside of their network and run on the LAN instead of having to give access to you.